Example of a prophecy for good being retracted
Maimonides, in his introduction to the Mishna (based on BT Berachot 7a) says that when God promises something good will happen, it will never be taken back. (However, a promise of something bad happening may be taken back if the person repents.)
This seems to be contradicted by a verse in last week's parsha (Deuteronomy 28:68):

And the LORD shall bring thee back into Egypt in ships, by the way whereof I said unto thee: ‘Thou shalt see it no more again’

How do we square these two texts?
